# What's wrong with my charset in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, encoding

I am trying to display a text, which is stored in an QLabel-Object, on the screen but I am having some conversion problems. 
When i press a certain key (QPushButton) on my on-screen keyboard, the character should be appended to my QLabel. This is my method:

```
void LoginKeyboard::setDigit(QChar digit)
{
    ui->loginInput->setText(text.append(digit));
}

void LoginKeyboard::on_Auth_letter_OE_clicked()
{
    setDigit('Ö');
}
```

When i run my program and do as I said, it shows some weird sign. I also get a warning from QT saying

```
multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
setDigit('Ã„');
```

I have read some similar Stackoverflow-topics but the solutions didn't work out for me. One suggestion was to change my encoding to utf-8 in QT which I already configured that way in my Qt when I set it up. Also didn't work out.
I also don't understand why my console is showing a different sign than my Qlabel when i print the char using cout. Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding an `L` before the character literal? Aka `L'Ö'`

Comment: Are your source files saved in UTF-8?

Comment: haha this L thing worked out :D:D:D thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Drew McGowen I solved this problem. The answer is simple to add an L before the charactar literal

Comment: I take it you're on Windows then?